# How to speed up mongoDB query

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, optimization

> I am working with this api, and i am getting the reponse back after 10sec or more then 10sec, what is wrong with query? how do i optimze this query so the reponse time will be less.
> I have also created index on each search and filters key, so while i am searching this will be using indexes but still i am getting the response that is taking too much time.

```
get = async (_params) => {
const params = _params
const { offset, limit } = params
let supplierProfiles = []
let searchQuery = {}
this.offset = offset || 0
this.queryLimit = limit || 5


if (params.search) {
  const SearchKey = new RegExp(params.search, 'i')
  searchQuery = {
    $or: [
      { refNo: SearchKey },
      { businessName: SearchKey },
      { tradingName: SearchKey },
      { 'agentTypes.name': SearchKey },
      { 'departments.name': SearchKey },
      { 'locality.name': SearchKey },
      { 'type.name': SearchKey },
      { 'status.name': SearchKey },
      { 'factories.name': SearchKey },
      { 'externalReferences.source': SearchKey },
      { 'externalReferences.id': SearchKey },
      { 'classification.name': SearchKey },
      { 'incoterms.name': SearchKey },
      { 'addresses.country.name': SearchKey },
    ],
  }
}
searchQuery.$and = []
if (params.status) {
  searchQuery.$and.push({ 'status.id': params.status })
}
if (params.agent_types) {
  searchQuery.$and.push({ 'agentTypes.id': params.agent_types })
}
if (params.departments) {
  searchQuery.$and.push({ 'departments.id': params.departments })
}
if (params.locality) {
  searchQuery.$and.push({ 'locality.id': params.locality })
}
if (params.type) {
  searchQuery.$and.push({ 'type.id': params.type })
}
if (params.external_references) {
  searchQuery.$and.push({ 'externalReferences.id': params.external_references })
}
if (params.classification) {
  searchQuery.$and.push({ 'classification.id': params.classification })
}
if (params.incoterms) {
  searchQuery.$and.push({ 'incoterms.id': params.incoterms })
}
if (params.created_at) {
  switch (params.created_at) {
    case 'today':
      searchQuery.$and.push({
        createdAt: {
          $gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
          $lt: moment().endOf('day').toDate(),
        },
      })
      break

    case 'thisweek':
      searchQuery.$and.push({
        createdAt: {
          $gte: moment().startOf('week').toDate(),
          $lt: moment().endOf('week').toDate(),
        },
      })
      break

    case 'thismonth':
      searchQuery.$and.push({
        createdAt: {
          $gte: moment().startOf('month').toDate(),
          $lt: moment().endOf('month').toDate(),
        },
      })
      break

    case 'thisyear':
      searchQuery.$and.push({
        createdAt: {
          $gte: moment().startOf('year').toDate(),
          $lt: moment().endOf('year').toDate(),
        },
      })
      break

    case 'customduration':
      searchQuery.$and.push({
        createdAt: {
          $gte: new Date(params.startdate), 
          $lt: new Date(params.enddate), //2022-08-29 ---format
        },
      })
      break
  }
}

if (searchQuery.$and?.length < 1) {
  delete searchQuery.$and
}

try {
  const count = SModel.countDocuments(searchQuery).lean()
  profiles = await SModel.find(searchQuery)
    .skip(parseInt(this.offset, 10))
    .limit(parseInt(this.queryLimit, 10))
    .lean()
    .sort({ refNo: 1 })
  return { data: fromCamelToSnake(profiles), total_count: await count }
} catch (err) {
  throw new Error(`Failed while fetching profile ${err}`)
}
```

}

> It is taking 10sec or more then 10 sec to response, i have only 3000 records in my collection.

Comment: Can you please provide the verbose explain (`.explain("allPlansExecution")`) for this query and the indexes (`.getIndexes()`) for the collection? Generally, doing a case insensitive regex search is not going to be very efficient, and if you do have an index for each of the 14 fields in the `$or` then that will probably be slower than a collection scan. Might have better luck using text search directly, either via a text index or by using Atlas Search

Comment: $text search is not supported by aws document DB

Comment: Are you using DocumentDB? You didn't state that in the question, and you tagged the question with `mongodb`. That's important clarification to make. In either case, it is still possible that having a bunch of individual indexes slows things down here. Checking `explain` may still help.  Also, is this an option for you? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/run-full-text-search-queries-on-amazon-documentdb-data-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service/